# What do I set the 'socket' to in lighttpd/fcgi?

Tags: configuration, lighttpd, fastcgi

I want to configure lighttpd to run fastcgi but I'm not sure what I should set the 'socket' to. What is the socket? Surely it doesn't expect me to create a socket before the program is actually running, that's impossible.

Comment: You can control in your app where the socket will be created on filesystem right? in /var/run/php-fcgi.sock or something?

Comment: @DanilaLadner What would the .sock file be used for? Would that simply be the file containing the UNIX socket?

Comment: Yes. You can always just use host name and port on which your fastcgi app is, for that you just ignore socket option.